# row_number() function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, row-number

I am using ROW_NUMBER function in oracle and trying to understand how it is going to behave when the partition by and order by clause holds the same data then how ranking will work (if there are duplicate records).

below is the sample dataset

```
select * from test
```

Result

```
Dept        salary  created date    
HR          500     25-Jul          
HR          200     25-Jul          
HR          500     26-Jul          
Accounts    300     25-Jan          
Accounts    300     26-Jan          
Accounts    300     27-Jan
```

i ran the row_number function based on above set

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Dept order by salary) as row_number
from test
```

result

```
Dept        salary  created date    row_number
HR          500     25-Jul          1
HR          200     25-Jul          1
HR          500     26-Jul          2
Accounts    300     25-Jan          1
Accounts    300     26-Jan          2
Accounts    300     27-Jan          3
```

As you can see the output above, i am using the Dept as partition by and salary as order by for row_number, it gave me the ranking 1,2,3. 
I am trying to understand here is that for the same data in the partition by and order by clause, does oracle assign the row_number based on when record entered into the system like in above "Accounts" "300" it gave the row_number 1 for the record which entered earliest in the system "25-Jan"

is there anywhere it is clearly mentioned that if it is doing partition by and order by on same data then ranking will be done based on when those records entered into the system.

Comment: No, It's got nothing to do with the value of `date` when you've not used it in `partition by` or `order by`. That's how `row_number()` functions as it assigns each row a unique number within the group. Tell us what you want.

Comment: thanks for your response. 
But still if there are duplicates based on the partition by clause then which record it will be assigning row num 1

Comment: In the example i gave, though ROW_NUMBER function is not using the date column, but there are 3 duplicates records for (based on dept and salary) how in the background oracle determine that i need to give the rank 1 to the record where created_date = "25-Jan" and rank 2 for the record where created_date= "26-Jan" and rank 3 for "27-Jan".
is it possible that it randomly assign the row_number() like 1 for "26-Jan", 2 for 25_jan and 3 for 27-Jan

When i tried in oracle by myself on this sample data it gives me the record based on which record entered into the system first.

Comment: It's indeterministic and not based on other columns (like date). Only when you've specified the `date` in the `order by` explicitly, it becomes deterministic.

Comment: `created_date` is part of your model and has no meaning for Oracle. So it's not going to choose to use it as a tie breaker. If your ORDER BY criteria are not sufficient to fix a sort order the result set is not guaranteed: you may get a pattern, you may not.

Comment: This means it is going to assign the row_number randomly in these cases.

Comment: Yes - randomly. Or at least you must treat it that way. Oracle will still assign the row numbers in some deterministic way (perhaps based on ROWID or who knows what else), but such "deterministic" behavior is not promised to follow any reasonable rules, it may change from one running of the query to another due to a multitude of reasons, etc. If you need to break the tie for whatever reason, you must do so *explicitly* in the `order by` part of the analytic clause.

Comment: Got it. thanks a lot for your time and help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand here is that for the same data in the partition by and order by clause, does oracle assign the row_number based on when record entered into the system like in above "Accounts" "300"

No, it does not.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless provided by explicitly by referring to column values.

If you are sorting by values that are the same, *there is no guarantee on the ordering of the rows*.  Note that running the same query twice can produce different results when there are ties in `order by` keys.  It is even possible within the same query.  This is true both for the `order by` clause and for analytic functions.

If you want a guarantee, then you need to include a unique column as the last sorting key (well, it could not be the last, but it would effectively be the last one).

Answer (score -1):

I guess you end result can be achieved using ROWID pseudocolumn as ROWID only generated when data entered into system -

```
SELECT T.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Dept order by salary, ROWID) as row_number
FROM test T
```

Comment: ROWID is not a reliable indicator of anything except a row's current location: comparing ROWIDs tells us nothing meaningful. If the OP wants a guaranteed order why wouldn't they use anything other than `order by salary, created_date`?

Comment: As per OP's last comment, 'ranking will be done based on when those records entered into the system.' I think we have no other way than ROWID.

Comment: Nope. That statement is asking whether Oracle documentation states that Oracle resolves ties in ORDER BY clause with record creation timestamp? Which the documentation doesn't say, because Oracle doesn't resolve such ties deterministically.